# Passing data containing a colon to a function

Tags: google-sheets

It seems that the colon in the A1 cell below is confusing the function.  It may think this is a range selector.  How can I fix this function so it will work?

```
A1: NASDAQ:AAPL

=GoogleFinance(A1, "close", TODAY()-1,  1, 1)
```

This returns #N/A...  If I hard-code the string "NASDAQ:AAPL" as parameter 1, it will work.  If I use just AAPL in A1 it will work.  In some cases, the exchange is required to make the symbol unique.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Is it possible the entry in A1 has a leading or trailing space? Also, what locale are you using (File, Spreadsheet settings)?

Comment: your right, I had spaces in the cell...

Comment: if you put your comment as an answer i'll check it off...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason is there are erroneous spaces in the cell (perhaps before or after the text).

Without such spaces, I can't reproduce your error.